# Saving 3D-plot in PDF 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, matplotlib-3d

I've generated a 3D plot with python and pyplot. I am able to export this plot to PDF. Which is quite boring and sometimes.. Flat 3D plots can be hard to read/understand.

However, PDF supports interactive 3D models, such as CAD models. This made me wonder if it is possible to export a 3D plot generated by matplotlib or something similar, to 3D PDF? This would be amazing to store beautiful 3D plots! If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Not so much an answer as a summary of my research so far:

- a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342276/pyplot-to-3d-pdf) asked pretty much the same but came to no conclusion
- .pdf supports two internal 3d formats - [u3d](http://www.pdf3d.com/u3d/) (since version 7), and [prc](http://www.pdf3d.com/about-prc/) (since version 8). prc is a more complicated but more compact format.
- (c. 2006): Acrobat 3d supports many more formats - over 40 - but does so by converting them to u3d for import ([reference](http://blogs.adobe.com/mfg/2006/11/what_3d_formats_can_acrobat_3d.html))
- (Dec 2013): matplotlib's drawing core is 2d only; mplot3d is just a workaround, everything gets projected to 2d before being rendered. ([reference](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2672/)) Link to [GlumPy](https://glumpy.github.io/)?

At the moment, I see two likely approaches:

- write a new 3d output engine for matplotlib to u3d
- write a 3d renderer for matplotlib to OpenGL (Acrobat 3d can capture the contents of an active OpenGL frame)

Comment: matplotlib doesn't serialize their figures like ggplot2 (R) or plotly, so it's nearly impossible to convert mpl figures from one format to another unfortunately. Discussion here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/wiki/MEP25

Answer (score -3):

I believe colorful material is better to turn on `rasterized=True` if you'd like to use PDF, otherwise sometimes the figure size can be too large and impossible to complete:

An example of 3D plot:

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

z_line = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000)
x_line = np.cos(z_line)
y_line = np.sin(z_line)
ax.plot3D(x_line, y_line, z_line, 'gray')

z_points = 15 * np.random.random(100)
x_points = np.cos(z_points) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
y_points = np.sin(z_points) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
ax.scatter3D(x_points, y_points, z_points, c=z_points, cmap='hsv',rasterized=True);

plt.savefig('test2.pdf',format='pdf')
plt.show()
```